# how to retrieve binary image from database in vb.net and insert the image in grid view

Tags: vb.net, image, gridview, binary

How to retrieve a binary image from a database using vb.net and insert the image into a GridView.

This is my DB

image (id as integer , img as varbinary(max))

Comment: What type of gridview are you talking about? asp.net's gridview, Winform's gridview? what?

Answer (score 0):

While you clarify the type of gridview you are referring to, here's how to insert the data in the database:

```
Using c As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString)
   c.Open()
   Dim command = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO yourtable(image) values (@image)", c)
   ' this is specific to the FileUploadControl but the idea is to get the
   'image in a byte array; however you do it, it doesn't matter
    Dim buffer(FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength) As Byte
    FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", buffer)
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()    
End Using
```

And assuming you are talking about an ASP .NET app, you can bind the data to the gridview as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                     <!--Trick to encode the bytes as a BASE64 string-->
                    <img width="100px" height="100px" src='data:image/png;base64,<%#System.Convert.ToBase64String(Eval("image"))%>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="Data Source=Your_ConnectionString_GoesHere" 
            ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [image] FROM [your_table_name_goes_here]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```